# D3 .rangeBands() returning NaN

Tags: javascript, jquery, d3.js

In the code below Chrome's debugger I get the following error

```
Error: Invalid value for <rect> attribute y="NaN"
```

when this is exectued

```
        this.options.barDemo.selectAll("rect")
            .data(data)
            .enter()
            .append("svg:rect")
            .attr("x", function (d, i) {
                //console.log(x(i));
                 return x(i);
            })
            .attr("y", function (d) {
                console.log(height - y(d.attributes.contract));
                return height - y(d.attributes.contract);
            })
            .attr("height", function (d) {
                console.log(y(d.attributes.contract));
                return y(d.attributes.contract);
            })
            .attr("width", barWidth)
            .attr("fill", "#2d578b");
```

I've isolated the problem to this function for the `y` coordinate value

```
y(d.attributes.contract)
```

My question is this: Given a value in between 0 and 200000, why would the above statement evaluate to `NaN` given `var y` is equal to this:

```
 var y = d3.scale.ordinal().domain([0, 200000]).rangeBands([height, 0]);
```

It's my understanding that the D3 `.ordinal()` function will return a coordinate based on where that value falls within a given range. This is my first time using D3, however, so any suggestions/hints/tips greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think an ordinal scale is the wrong choice here. An ordinal scale maps values the discrete set of values in the domain directly to values in the range, so it will only return a value if you pass it one of the values in the domain. In your case it will return the height when you pass 0, and 0 when you pass 200000. Anything else will return NaN.

Probably what you want is a [linear scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#linear). Linear scales take in a continuous range, and then return a value within the range. Given this scale:

```
var y = d3.scale.linear().domain([0, 200000]).range([height, 0]);
```

you can pass it any value between 0 and 200000 and it will return a value between height and 0.

Answer (score 0):

I was getting NaN in a different scenario because I was passing `undefined` as my padding when configuring via `.rangeBands([0,1], padding)`. Something to watch out for.